# How to increase atomic DMA coherent pool?

Tags: linux, kernel-parameters

I recently attempted to compile a device driver (Xilinx XAPP1052) on Fedora Workstation 20. It gave me the following error.

> ERROR: 256 KiB atomic DMA coherent pool is too small!
>
> Please increase it with coherent_pool= kernel parameter

How would I go about doing this? Is there a command that lets me change the coherent_pool parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the message says, use `coherent_pool=<size>` kernel (boot) parameter.

With `grub`, select the desired kernel, press <kbd>e</kbd> to modify the boot entry, then append the line starting with `kernel` with the option. This change won't be preserved across reboots.

If you want the change permanent, append the option to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="... coherent_pool=<size>"
```

Remeber to run `update-grub` to write the new configuration files.

Comment: In /etc/default, I see nss, rmt, and useradd, but no grub. I also don't see grub when I boot up. Fedora is the only OS on this device. Is there somewhere else I would look?

Comment: Are you using grub, or some other boot loader?

Comment: I'm not sure (I'm new to Linux). How would I see what bootloader I'm using? I installed Fedora on this device by flashing the device's eMMC if that makes a difference.

Comment: If your system isn't using grub, you need to investigate how your system boots and how to modify the kernel boot parameters. The boot files are stored at `/boot`, but they likely get automatically overwritten during kernel updates.